# Java: counting occurence of words, program counts 'empty' words

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, split, punctuation

I have a program that takes input from a text file , removes the punctuation and then splits by single space and tallies the results into a map.  I can get it to work but I am getting an empty result in the map as well and I don't know what gives:

scanner takes an input:

```
try
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            String nextLine;
            while (input.hasNextLine())
            {
                nextLine = input.nextLine().trim();
                processLine(nextLine, occurrenceMap);
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("Something has gone wrong!");}
```

The text file that it is pullinng from is a king james version of the bible
then a separate function processes each line:

```
//String[] words = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", " ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+"); // runtime for  bible.txt is ~1600ms

// changed to simple iteration and the program ran MUCH faster:

char[] letters = line.trim().toCharArray();
for (int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
{
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(letters[i])) {continue;}
    else {letters[i] = ' ';}
}

String punctuationFree = new String(letters);
String[] words = punctuationFree.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");

// add each word to the frequency map:
for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
{
    if (! map.containsKey(words[i]))
    {
        map.put(words[i], 1);
    }
    else
    {
        int value = (int)map.get(words[i]);
        map.put(words[i], ++value);
    }
}
```

As you can see I first did it with a replace all, and then i came up with my own funky iterative method (which seems to run faster).  In both cases when I print out the results using PrintWriter I am getting a strange entry at the beginning:

```
num occurences/ (number /word)

25307 :     // what is up with this empty value ?
1 : 000     // the results continue in sorted order
2830 : 1
2122 : 10
6 : 100
9 : 101
29 : 102
23 : 103
36 : 104
46 : 105
49 : 106
```

I have tried changing `String[] words = punctuationFree.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");` to .split("\s+") and .split(" ") but I am still getting this empty value in the results.

I am trying to only count occurences of words and numbers, why am I getting this empty value ?

UPDATE:  at the suggestion that Character.isLetterOrDigit() might be returning unwanted characters I rewrote the checks as so to only get characters I want.  I nonetheless am still getting a mystery empty value:

```
for (int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
    {
        if ((letters[i] >= 'a' && letters[i] <= 'z') || 
           (letters[i] >= 'A' && letters[i] <= 'Z'))
           {continue;}
        else if (letters[i] >= '0' && letters[i] <= '9')
           {continue;}
        else if ((letters[i] == ' ')||(letters[i] =='\n')||(letters[i] == '\t'))
           {continue;}
        else
            letters[i] = ' ';
    }
```

Comment: It would help to know what is in `line`.

Comment: i'll update the question...

Comment: It would *still* help to know what is in `line`, and not just a description of what is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing but the Character method `IsLetterOrDigit` is defined to work on the whole unicode range.  Per the document [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletterordigit?view=netframework-4.8), it includes all "Valid letters and decimal digits are members of the following categories in UnicodeCategory: UppercaseLetter, LowercaseLetter, TitlecaseLetter, ModifierLetter, OtherLetter, or DecimalDigitNumber."

I think that this method is keeping Characters (ModifierLetter and/ or OtherLetter in particular) you do not want and which are not included in your font so you cannot see them.

**Edit 1**:
I tested your algorithm.  It turns out that a blank line circumvents your tests because it skips the for loop.  You need to add a line length just after you read a line from the file line this:

```
if (nextLine.length() == 0) {continue;}
```

**Edit 2**: Also, since you are scanning every character to weed out the "non-word and non-digits", you could also incorporate the logic to create the words and add them to the collection.  Like this maybe:

```
private static void WordSplitTest(String line) {
    char[] letters = line.trim().toCharArray();

    boolean gotWord = false;

    String word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(letters[i])) {

            if(!gotWord) {continue;}

            gotWord = false;

            AddWord(word);
        }
        if (gotWord) {
            word += Character.toString(letters[i]);
        }
    }
}

private static void AddWord(String word) {
    if (!map.containsKey(word)) {
        map.put(word, 1);
    } else {
        int value = (int) map.get(word);
        map.put(word, ++value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I redid the Character checks to only check for ASCII using < and > and I am still getting the same results in the output

Comment: Thanks a lot !  That did not occur to me about blank lines.  I got this to work in Python using a very similar algorithm but I guess the blank lines were not registering in Java.

Comment: So I put the `if (nextLine.length() == 0) {continue;}` in the step processing each character and it was still letting 35 empty words through. So I followed your advice and put the same check when then the words were added to the map and like Pokemon: I got them all.  Thanks again.